# Is it possible to remap PrevTab and NextTab to <c-h> and <c-l> on Chrome/Brave?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, 20.04, google-chrome, brave

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04, Brave 84.1.11.97. I'd like to remap PrevTab and NextTab to  and  respectively. Problem is, Brave seems not to support custom shortcuts, and the extensions available are Windows-only. Is there any alternative way to make those shortcuts work on either Chrome or Brave?

Comment: Your question presently reads, "I'd like to remap PrevTab and NextTab to and respectively." You seem to have lost some words there. Kindly edit so that your question makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do it. There is a nice extension called Shortkeys that costs 2 usd and allows remapping PrevTab and NextTab on Chrome. **It is a fair ask so I highly recommend buying it to support the developer.** For some reason, though, I didn't manage to install it on Brave: I get a "not authorized" error when installing it. Fortunately, the code is open source so we can build it manually.

```
git clone https://github.com/mikecrittenden/shortkeys
cd shortkeys
npm i
npm run build chrome
```

This will place a `shortkeys.v3.0.8.chrome.zip` file on the `shortkeys/packages` directory. Unzip that file on the same directory. There should be a `shortkeys/packages/manifest.json` file now. Then open brave, type `brave://extensions` on the url bar, activate "developer mode" on the top/right corner, click "load unpacked" on the top/left corner, navigate to the `shortkeys/packages` directory and press enter. The extension should now be added. Now go to `brave://extensions/shortcuts` and remap the keys you want to.